# Add certain CSS style's ONLY when the site is viewed in an iframe or lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to remove my header / footer whenever my website is viewed in an iframe / lightbox. I searched the web around a bit and came up with the following code:

```
if (window.top!=window.self)
    {
  // In a Frame or IFrame
echo "<style> 
         .sticky-wrapper{ display: none !important;} 
         .header-contact-bar {display: none !important;}
         #as.footer { display: none !important;}
      </style>";
    }
    else
    {
  // Not in a frame
    }
```

The CSS gets changed in the lightbox too but also on my site. The problem is. I can't figure out why it is also adding the css when im not in an lightbox / iframe.

1. Am I doing something worng with the code?
2. Does the code work at all?
3. Do I have to put something in the `else` statement?
4. So yes. What?

Comment: can you share your website url

Comment: @Kyojimaru http://www.viscongroup.eu

Comment: Maybe you could use 
`window.location != window.parent.location`

Instead of what you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own Solution after puzzling quite a while.

```
<script>

        if( self != top ) {
   headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML;
   var frameCSS = headTag + '<style type="text/css">.sticky-wrapper{ display: none !important;}  .header-contact-bar {display: none !important;} #as.footer { display: none !important;}</style>';
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = frameCSS;
}
  </script>
```